# I want my nav bar to appear on the opposite side of my logo

Tags: html, css

I want my header to appear as such, with the logo on one side and the nav bar on the other side:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBnnF.png)

It currently appears with the logo and nav bar stacked on top of each other, on the left side: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBgm2.png)

I tried using a flex display, and justifying the content but that didn't work. Any ideas? Here's the code pen: `Why do I need to have code to link a codepen lol` https://codepen.io/jalal_b/pen/ZEpmzzX

Comment: Try to analyse the freeCodeCamp example code and learn with it the basics of responsive web design. (I finished this course successfully with certification)

Comment: _Why do I need to have code to link a codepen lol_ you don't. you have to put your code directly in your question with the tools available. You got a warning about this and circumvented it

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. A question should always contain a minimal reproduciable code snippet. You even got a warning for only posting a codepen link without a code snippet. If you close your code-pen or change the content, then this question would hold no further value to the community and as such be useless. Also it is expected, that you have done at least some kind of research efford. As such, please state what you have tried so far, and where exectly you're stuck by solving it on your own!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to add to your styles:

```css
#header { display: flex; }
#nav-bar { flex: 1; }
#nav-bar ul { display: block }
#nav-bar ul li { 
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
}
```

You might need to fit into your design.

Here is an article about `flex`-box in CSS if you want to learn more: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Good luck! ✌️

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to a snippet below.

I simply added this code to your CSS:

```
#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Then set `display: inline` on your list items:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

You will probably need to adjust your layout a bit to space out the list items a bit more.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Staatliches&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway&display=swap');

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#header-img {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #BEB7A4;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<div id="page-wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img 
           id="header-img"
           src="data:image/png;base64,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"
           alt="sporks logo"/>
    </div>
      
<nav id="nav-bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#how-to-use">How To Use</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href="#where-to-buy">Where To Buy</a></li>
  </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```